# Expressão regular para criar uma linha dum jogo do galo (jogo da velha)

Tags: regex, python-3.x

Estou a tentar usar um pattern para encontrar uma certa linha num file, mas não está funcionando.

Esta é o meu pattern: `row = re.compile(r"(|\s[OX\s]\s{3}|)")`

Com essa eu quero encontrar basicamente este pattern: `|   | O | X |`, ou seja quero que no meio dos pipes `|   |` possa existir só no lado esquerdo: `espaço`, no meio: `0` or `X` ou `espaço`, direito: `espaço`. Gostaria que me retornasse `None` se o pattern não é exatamente assim, mas não está funcionando.

```
row = re.compile(r"(|\s[OX\s]\s{3}|)")
exp = re.match(row, line)
```

Se `line` é diferente, por examplo em vez de `| X |   |   |`, tenho `| X    |`, funciona na mesma!

Qual é o problema?

Answer (score 3):

Lembrando que o `|` é um carácter especial nas expressos regulares e representa o `or` para capturá-lo literalmente você deve usa `\|`

Com esta expressão creio que você pode achar o que deseja.

```
\|\s+(o|x| )\s+\|
```

basicamente o que ela faz é buscar

*|* **+** conector **+** *|*

Eu estou usando o "`o`" e o "`x`" minúsculos, não sei se o Python comporta por o i no final semelhante a  javascript `/\|\s+(o|x| )\s+\|/i` para buscar maiúsculo e minusculo ao mesmo tempo, contudo caso seja necessario altere para `\|\s+(o|O|x|X| )\s+\|`.

Comment: Site para teste http://regex101.com/r/bL5mO0/1

Answer (score 0):

tenta usar desta forma `\|\s\|([OX\s]\|x\S)`.

casa com:

`| |O|x|`, `| |X|X|`.

mas não casa com:

`|X| | |`, `|O| | |`.